# How can add custom fonts and images to my picker?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, fonts, picker

I have a picker in my app that displays the currently picked option as its label. However, I can't seem to figure out how to change the font used by the picker for its label and for displaying all the picker options. I would also like to put an icon in front of the text of the picker that's part of the picker button but doesn't change as the text does so that a user could click both the text and the icon for the picker to appear.

Here's the code I am using for my picker:

```
var fylker = ["Norge", "Akershus", "Agder", "Buskerud", "Finnmark", "Innlandet", "Møre og Romsdal", "Nordland", "Oslo", "Østfold", "Rogaland", "Troms", "Trøndelag", "Vestfold og Telemark", "Vestland"]
```

```
Picker("Fylke", selection: $selectedFylke) {
                            ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
```

I've already tried things like:

```
Picker("Fylke", selection: $selectedFylke) {
                            ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0).font(.custom("Custom-Bold", size: 34))
                            }
                        }
```

and

```
Picker("Fylke", selection: $selectedFylke) {
                            ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) {
                                HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                                Text($0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

to no avail

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 
What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: You'd have to extend `Picker` to have a custom design, use `UIKit`, or design your own completely. Try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATgOV70YcI8

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand i think you could try to use a font modifier to add your custom font and add image inside HStack so they are beside each other like that

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
var fylker = ["Norge", "Akershus", "Agder", "Buskerud", "Finnmark", 
 "Innlandet", "Møre og Romsdal", "Nordland", "Oslo", "Østfold", 
 "Rogaland", "Troms", "Trøndelag", "Vestfold og Telemark", "Vestland"]
@State var selectedFylke:String = ""

var body: some View {
    Picker("Fylke", selection: $selectedFylke) {
        ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) { I in
            HStack(){
                Text(I).font(Font.custom("Font-Family-Name", size: 16))
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
            }.tag(I)
        }
    }.frame(width: 200, height: 60, alignment:.center).background(Color.red)
    
}
}

  struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

also if you mean to add the image beside the picker so they seemed as a button picker you can do that

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
var fylker = ["Norge", "Akershus", "Agder", "Buskerud", "Finnmark", 
 "Innlandet", "Møre og Romsdal", "Nordland", "Oslo", "Østfold", 
  "Rogaland", "Troms", "Trøndelag", "Vestfold og Telemark", "Vestland"]
   @State var selectedFylke:String = ""

 var body: some View {
    HStack(){
    Image(systemName: "pencil").foregroundColor(.white)
    Picker("search", selection: $selectedFylke) {
        ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) {
                Text($0).font(Font.custom("Font-Family-Name", size: 16))
        }
    }
    }.frame(width: 200, height: 60, alignment: 
     .center).background(Color.red).background(Color.red).cornerRadius(30)
   }
 }

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SwiftUIView()
   }
 }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this method doesn't seem to actually change the font used by the picker am afraid. I've aslo already placed an icon next to my picker in an HStack, but that's not what I want to do. I'd like to make the icon part of the picker so that a user can click both the text or the icon for the picker to show.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach to set the font used by the `Picker`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let fylker = ["Norge", "Akershus", "Agder", "Buskerud", "Finnmark",
                  "Innlandet", "Møre og Romsdal", "Nordland", "Oslo", "Østfold",
                  "Rogaland", "Troms", "Trøndelag", "Vestfold og Telemark", "Vestland"]
    
    @State var selectedFylke = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Fylke", selection: $selectedFylke) {
            ForEach(fylker, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.circle")
                    Text(item)
                }
                .font(.custom("Custom-Bold", size: 34)) // for both the Text and the Image
                .tag(item)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(.wheel) // <-- here
    }
}
```

This does **not** work with pickerStyle: `automatic`, `menu` and `segmented`